# angular2 service method not getting invoked

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I tried to create a sample angular2 service and consume it, but I am not sure about the mistake that i have done. the service method couldn't be called by the component, Please see the plunker for more details  https://plnkr.co/edit/tlnGU9Er6GxsOaUMCZZG?p=preview

My service code looks like below

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers, Response, JSONP_PROVIDERS, Jsonp } from 'angular2/http';
import { Configuration } from './Configuration';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

///Service class to call REST API
@Injectable()
export class SampleService {
    items: Array<any>;

    constructor() {
        this.items = [
            { name: 'Test1' },
            { name: 'Test2' },
            { name: 'Test3' }
        ];
    }

    getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use New -> Angular -> 2.0 TS http://take.ms/AJTLh

Comment: you're index.html page is not including any anuglar2 code and it isn't set up to do the transpiling from typescript to javascript using System.js.  Consider following this tutorial to complete the missing peices: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Note that your component file name is `SampleCompoent.ts`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I followed the steps suggested above..Created a new angular2 app, referred all the required references from CDN. still the service method is not invoked in the component. what is it I am missing? please refer the new plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/KZ59wc5e4hpdZzq5UL4X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the @Injectable service in the array of providers when you bootstrap the app (in your case `bootstrap(SampleComponent, [SampleService])`) or inside the providers array in the component. More on Dependency injection you can read here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html.

After you add it as a provider, whenever you inject it in the class constructor, the component will be able to resolve it. It will be clear how the tree of dependency injection works after you read that link :)

Also in the plunkr you have two components with the same selector ('my-app') which I guess is also a mistake.

Comment: I did all the changes suggested by you, still not working as expected.can you please check in the plunker and correct my mistakes?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/hI7z0Hnx7ssgDdwd3n12?p=preview Here you go.. i forked it and update it.. you had 2 problems. The first one was that in bootstrap.ts you did not have imported the service before using it in the dependency array ```import {SampleService} from './SampleService'```. Second you imported the bootstrap function itself from wrong place (you are not using the RC version there but a beta) and it is in ```import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';``` not in ```@angular/...```. And third the word ```let``` in the ngFor did not exist in beta so I changed it with #item